# Looking for Ecommerce engine or service for sharing sales

Tags: e-commerce

I am looking for the service or library to share the sales online. I am developging ecommerce site which will be selling media content. The content creator can upload their stuff and sell on our site. When he sells the product he will receive the 80% and I will receive 20%. Since the money is involved in I want this part to be as transparent as possible. Maybe there might be saas solution available so that I can call api to send sales and money can be split and he can get the moeny anytime he wants through paypal or some other method. Let me know if you know anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout the following links, I would recommend Stripe. Also if allowing payments via paypal the checkout the third link.

https://stripe.com/blog/send-payouts-with-stripe

https://www.wepay.com/developer/usecases/split-chained-payments.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/